# What about the libdbus-1-dev?

Tags: linux, dbus, linux-mint

after I installed the new Linux Mint 18-1 KDE I was gathering the parts for the development in C++, such as QT Creator and libraries...
With the "old" Linux Mint 17 I used this libdbus-1-dev for IPC, so I wanted to install this lib again. But there is now a warning because of removing other libs, such as:

dbus-x11, libdbus-1-3, libdbus-1-3:i386, dbus

Now I wondering if I can safely install the libdbus-1-dev...

I hope you can help me with this.

Best regards

Earlybite

Comment: Please post the actual warning message you get from your package manager. Without the warning message, answering this is hard.

Comment: Meanwhile I installed this libdbus-1-dev, and all seems to be fine. So now I do not know anymore the correct sentence. But for free is it: Installing libdus-1-dev will remove the following packages dbus-x11, libdbus-1-3, libdbus-1-3:i386, dbus. And I ask, because I still do not know what effect it exactly took for the system/distribution of my Linux Mint 18-1... BTW: I never before noticed something about e.g. dbus-x11. And a searched brought no installed libs or such.